# Facebook comments on a popup div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-comments

i have a problem with facebook comments and displaying them on a popup div. The problem is they share same comments but i have different data-href. Here is my code:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT ID_Story,Story,Down,Up from Story LIMIT $startrow, $nr_evenimente_pagina";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
echo'<div id="story"><div id="header_title"><h2>Love Lock Stories</h2>
<h3>Whats your story?</h3></div>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
 echo'  
    <div class="story_container">   

<h1>test</h1><br>
<p>'.$row['Story'].'</p>    


 <p> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById(\'light\').style.display=\'block\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'block\'">Click here for facebook comments</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content"><div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/story.php?active=2&id='.$row['ID_Story'].'" data-numposts="3" data-width="400" data-colorscheme="light"></div> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById(\'light\').style.display=\'none\';document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display=\'none\'">Close</a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

    ';


echo'</div></div>';
}
```

Here is the link where i have the comments [Link](http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/story.php?active=2&pag=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same `id="light"` on each of the pop ups, change this to a class and it should work. `id`s need to be distinct in the same document.

If you make it a class you'll need to use something like `$(this).find('.light')` or `$(this).closest('.light')` or reference it directly like `$(this).parent().siblings('.light')`

Comment: How can i use direct url if i get the unique id from database and i have it in a while? it's dinamic content

Comment: Use inspect element and you can see the same `id` value for each comment popup on a page.

Comment: if u inspect the code before popup it's different id on each div but i dont know why the popup takes same id

Comment: updated answer, you're using the same `id` on each popup, `id`s are distinct in a document, and can only exist once.

Comment: hehe thnx alot mate, i added an unique id to the id light and it's working, i dont know how the hell i didnt notice that i use same id on same page. i'm to tired, i was looking at the php id from the facebook dinamic link. Thnx alot